# OpenCV 3 for Python 3.5 in CentOS 7

Tags: python, opencv, centos, centos7, libpng

I am trying to install OpenCV for Python in CentOS and I get the following error. I got it working with the same exact command in OSX:

```
(py35) [jalal@goku ~]$ conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/grad3/jalal/anaconda3/envs/py35:
#
opencv3                   3.2.0               np111py35_0    menpo
(py35) [jalal@goku ~]$ python
Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 13 2017, 11:22:58) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>> quit()
(py35) [jalal@goku ~]$ conda install -c menpo opencv3
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/grad3/jalal/anaconda3/envs/py35:
#
opencv3                   3.2.0               np111py35_0    menpo
(py35) [jalal@goku ~]$ python
Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 13 2017, 11:22:58) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>>
```

A little about my system information:

```
(py35) [jalal@goku ~]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 
Release:    7.4.1708
Codename:   Core
(py35) [jalal@goku ~]$ uname -a
Linux goku.bu.edu 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 20 20:32:50 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Additional information: I am not a sudoer on my machine (it is a lab machine).